syslog logging driver giving the error protocol wrong type for socket
I have a service defined via docker compose (see definition below). When I tried to start this service via docker-compose -f  up --wait -d my_service, I get the error
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to initialize logging driver: dial unix /dev/log: connect: protocol wrong type for socket

On my host server where I'm executing the docker compose cmd, I see the socket exists and my user has write perms:
srw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 0 Aug 29  2023 /dev/log

service definition:
  my_service:
    command: <omitted>
    image: <omitted>
    volumes:
      - "/dev/log:/dev/log"
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "unix:///dev/log"
        tag: "my_service"

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Syslog over the network uses UDP sockets; UDP is a datagram-based protocol as opposed to the streaming style of TCP connections.
Similarly, syslog over Unix sockets uses a datagram protocol. That means you need to use unixgram:///dev/log instead of unix:///dev/log:
  my_service:
    command: <omitted>
    image: <omitted>
    volumes:
      - "/dev/log:/dev/log"
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "unixgram:///dev/log"
        tag: "my_service"

The protocol options are documented in the syslog logging driver documentation.
See also the discussion on issue #18903.

I did see the linked discussion, but had thought it was resolved given wzyboy's linking to a merged PR that supposedly fixes the issue. These topics are quite new to me, but I see switching to unixgram does work indeed. Another thing that works is if I remove syslog-address. Why does it work in this case, and what is happening behind the scenes?

Actually if i don't specify a syslog-address, is it just defaulting to "unixgram:///dev/log"

RIght; that came up in the issue.

Thanks -- another question after reading up on unixgram is that messages sent aren't guaranteed to be in order, which might be problematic for my use case where I'm trying to log panic messages, which would be better if they were logged in order. Is there a way to enable ordering using syslog?

You would need a tcp-based (or streaming-socket based) logging service, and a corresponding logging driver. There are a number of logging drivers supported by docker. I'm not famliar with any of them, so I can't provide any guidance on that front. That said, I have never encountered a problem with out-of-order messages.

I see, thanks for all the help. One more question -- though it might be off topic here -- but do you know if there's an easy way to configure syslog to only record stderr (I don't need stdout in this case)

That seems like it would be better asked as a new question. If you control the image, you can just redirect stdout to /dev/null.
