rsyslogd: omfile: creating parent directories for file 'Permission denied' failed: /home/<user>/logs/docker/log
I'm getting the following error (note that rsyslogd is run as root)
rsyslogd: omfile: creating parent directories for file  'Permission denied' failed: /home/<user>/logs/docker/log

This directory has permissions:
drwxr-xr-x. 2 <user> <group>      6 Sep 23 12:20 docker

Regardless of permissions, because rsyslogd is run as root, I think there should be no problem with this?
ps -eo user,group,pid,comm | grep rsyslogd
root     root     14910 rsyslogd

I don't have root access, but just had the person with root access check and they can write to /home/<user>/logs/docker/log via vim, so this suggests it's rsyslogd related.
rsyslogd 8.24.0-57.el7_9.3, compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.


You seem to have inverted the error "Permission denied" and the filename. Are you using SELinux or something similar? If rsyslogd is running inside a docker container, doesn't /home/... map to some other place in the real filesystem? What is the rsyslogd version number (rsyslogd -version)?

@meuh Sorry what do you mean by "inverted?" I copy and pasted the error message from the error log. The ordering shown is what I see in the error log. I ran sestatus and see SELinux status:                 disabled. I just edited the version number in to the OP

@meuh I'm actually not sure how rsyslog is working in this case, but this is indeed in the context of a docker container. I have a service defined (see my other post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/783824/syslog-logging-driver-giving-the-error-protocol-wrong-type-for-socket) . I thought rsyslogd is running on the host and it's receiving lots at the linux socket from the container.

I hvae a custom config file in /etc/rsyslog.d/custom.conf that has if $programname == '<service_name>_syslog' then /home/<user>/logs/docker/log. I believe this is all happening on the host

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/mp91sp/rsyslog_status_error_omfile_creating_parent/ another user years ago had the same error (yes, it does look out of order to me too, but that's what i'm seeing in the printed log)

Sorry for all the comments. I just realized I ran sestatus on the wrong server, and I see SELinux status:                 enabled SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux Loaded policy name:             targeted Current mode:                   enforcing Mode from config file:          enforcing Policy MLS status:              enabled Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed Max kernel policy version:      31
so it is indeed enabled
